# JPA, Hibernate, PostgreSQL issue with coalesce parameter

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA query which goes something like

`select foo from Foo foo where foo.parent = coalesce(:parent, foo.parent)`

`.setParameter("parent", 1)` works but
`.setParameter("parent", null)` throws a

**COALESCE types bytea and integer cannot be matched**

I've tried various cast() around the parameter but that results in

**cannot cast type bytea to integer**

and using a ParameterExpression doesn't help either

Pointers appreciated,
Nik

Comment: Why are you trying to cast? Store the values with proper types.

Comment: one workaround appears to be to rewrite the condition as

`(foo.parent = :parent or :parent is null)`

Comment: You'll likely need the workaround, as I suspect setting NULL as the parameter value is failing for you as the JDBC statement needs to know the type and so defaults to bytea, causing issues in the database. JPA doesn't have a mechanism to pass through the type yourself though providers native api might

Comment: The cast was just something I tried to get around the fact that the column is integer and I assumed the passed in null would also implicitly be converted but no.

It probably has something to do with the fact that even the JDBC setNull has a second Types.* paramter